# Form.is_valid in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a problem with a form validation in Django.
I have this in views.py:

```
def n_visita(request, id_c):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = FormularioVisita(data=request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            ···
            save_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        formulario = FormularioVisita(idc=id_c)
        ···
        return...
```

And this in forms.py:

```
class FormularioVisita(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visita

    def __init__(self, idc=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormularioVisita, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["IdCita"].queryset = Citas.objects.filter(id=idc,Dia=date.today(),espera=True,estado=True)
```

This returns a single registry (because I give the "id"), show that option in the "select", all works fine.
But when I do click in "Save" button Django say "Choose a valid option" and not show me one option in "select".
What can I do? I need change the field to show the unique option of the queryset returns?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in idc when you instantiate the form in the POST block too.

Comment: formulario = FormularioVisita(data=request.POST, id=id_c)
is that correct?

Comment: formulario = FormularioVisita(data=request.POST, idc=id_c)

Comment: Ok, that's right, but do not work. Django still says the same message.